# iPhone : Problem with HTML while displaying it in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios4, uiwebview

In my app

I am generating the report using html and displaying it in UIWebView.

I am using Html table for formatting data in webview.

Attaching some screen shot for better understanding :

[image]

[image]

As Shown in the second screen's first round mark up, table alignment is misplaced.

The code which I use for generating this table is as following.

```
 [html appendFormat:@"<h3 style =\"font-family: Arial\">Expressive <h3><br/>"];

                    NSString *htmlString1= @"<table border=\"1\" style=\"width: 100%; border: 1px #000 solid; border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 13px; font-family: sans-serif;\">";

                    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) //Two Rows
                    {  
                        htmlString1 = [htmlString1 stringByAppendingString:@"<tr>"];

                        for (int j=0; j<2; j++) //Two Columns
                        {  
                            if (i==0)
                            {
                                if(j==0)
                                {
                                    htmlString1 = [htmlString1 stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<th style=\"text-align:center;font-size:16;width:30;height:20\"><b>Correct-%.00f%%</b></th>",correctPercent]];

                                }
                                else if(j==1)
                                {
                                    htmlString1 = [htmlString1 stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<th style=\"text-align:center;font-size:16;width:30;height:20\"><b>Incorrect-%.00f%%</b></th>",incorrectPercent]];

                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if(j==0)
                                {
                                    NSString *val = @"";
                                    if([[[newArray valueForKey:@"Expressive"]valueForKey:@"CorrectResults"] count]>0)
                                    {
                                        val = [[[newArray valueForKey:@"Expressive"]valueForKey:@"CorrectResults"] componentsJoinedByString:@"<br/>"];
                                    }
                                    htmlString1 = [htmlString1 stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<td style=\"text-align:center;width:40%;height:50;\">%@</td>",val]];  //E

                                }
                                else if(j==1)
                                {
                                    NSString *val = @"";
                                    if([[[newArray valueForKey:@"Expressive"] valueForKey:@"InCorrectResults"] count]>0)
                                    {
                                        val = [[[newArray valueForKey:@"Expressive"]valueForKey:@"InCorrectResults"] componentsJoinedByString:@"<br/>"];
                                    }
                                    htmlString1 = [htmlString1 stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<td style=\"text-align:center;width:40%;height:50;\">%@</td>",val]];

                                }

                            }

                        }
                        htmlString1 = [htmlString1 stringByAppendingString:@"</tr>"];
                    }

                    htmlString1 = [htmlString1 stringByAppendingString:@"</table>"];

                    [html appendString:htmlString1];
                    [html appendString:@"<br/>"];
```

How do I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `px` or `%` to designate the width of the columns:

```
htmlString1 = [htmlString1 stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<th style=\"text-align:center;font-size:16;width:30%;height:20px\"><b>Correct-%.00f%%</b></th>",correctPercent]];
```

etc...

Comment: I have tried with `%` but still I am not getting proper Html table!

Comment: even tried with `px`, but still not working. Any other solution ?

Comment: If % and px don't do what they are supposed to do, I wouldn't know. Note that both columns must add up to 100%. If you set a width in the <th>, there is no need to set it in the <td> anymore.